# Let p be a prime. If range(f) has an element of order p, then G has an element of order p.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working through [A Book Of Abstract Algebra](http://a.co/9f9b0oe), and in the chapter on homomorphisms, it has this question:

> Let $f:G\to H$ be a group homomorphism. Let $p$ be a prime. If $\mathrm{range}(f)$ has an element of order $p$, then $G$ has an element of order $p$.

I actually can't see how this could be true. Take G = the set of all integers, H = the parity group (`odd`, `even`). The homomorphism maps every integer to `odd` or `even`. H has one element of order 2: `odd`. 2 is prime. But there's no element with order 2 in G -- every element has infinite order.

Comment: I think that it holds if $G$ is finite.

Comment: It holds if $G$ is a torsion group, i.e. every element of $G$ has finite order.  But there's no need for $p$ to be prime.

Comment: I expect the text gave more information about $G$ than you are sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \in G$, and let $f(a) \in \text{range}(f)$ be the element of order $p$, where $p$ is prime.

Since the order of any element in the group divides the order of the group, we have $\text{ord }a\text{ } | \text{ }|G|.$

We also know that for a homomorphism $f$, for all $a \in G$ we have $\text{ord }f(a) | \text{ ord }a.$

Therefore, $\text{ord } f(a) \text{ } | \text{ }|G|.$

That is, we have  $ p | \text{ }|G|.$

Now simply apply Cauchy's theorem to see that $G$ has an element of order $p$.

As some of the comments alluded to, this result only holds for finite groups.